# Iteratively copy a directory's contents to multiple other directories in OS X Terminal (bash)

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have a directory (`dir1`, say) where each sub-directory contains the same contents. Like this:

```
dir1
  sub1
    subsub1
    file1
    file2
    subsub2
    [etc.]
  sub2
    [same as in sub1]
  sub3
    [...]
  aberration
```

So, you see, there's also one sub-directory which is different.

Then, I have another directory (`dir2`), which has contents that I would like to use to replace the contents of each of `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`, etc., but **NOT** of `aberration`. I would like to overwrite any files and directories in the target (where `dir2/subsub1` would replace the entire `dir1/sub5/subsub1` directory, regardless of its contents). [Edit: I realized I had dir1 and dir2 reversed in this previous sentence. I have edited it to correct the error.]

Is there a single command I can run to accomplish this? I've looked at `cp` with `xargs` and `rsync` with a `for` loop, but I've gotten my brain in a twist.

I'm also happy to write this as a shell script, but I'm still lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superficially:

```
cd /path/to/dir1
cp -rf sub* /path/to/dir2
```

As a technique, it relied on being able to distinguish `aberration` from `sub1` etc via the glob pattern `sub*`.  Adapt that to suit the details of your environment.  If the worst comes to the worst, create a file with the list of non-aberrational directory names:

```
cp -rf $(<non-aberrational-names) /path/to/dir2
```

This won't remove files found under dir2/subN that are not in dir1/subN.  For that, you'd probably add:

```
cd /path/to/dir2 &&
rm -fr sub*
cd /path/to/dir1
cp -fr sub* /path/to/dir2
```

Be cautious - the `rm -fr` is dangerous.

---

In a comment, I noted:

> If you value your sanity, use consistent names. If you're hobbled by other people's insanity, then you'll have to specify a mapping between the directories under `/path/to/dir1` and `/path/to/dir2`, probably by a file (and let's hope for your sake that the pathnames don't contain spaces!). You can then do: `while read src dst; do cp -fr $src $dst; done < directory-mapping-file`.

To which the response was:

> Ah yes, my sanity. Already mostly gone, I'm afraid, and these subdirs are client names. My decision, but an old one that I can't really change now. So this seems like it would work fine for me with the mapping file. But if you wouldn't mind, can you walk me through what the file would look like?

Ah yes, I'm familiar with finding that I was not entirely sane in times long past and that I have to live with the consequences.

The scheme I have in mind, assuming that pathnames do not include spaces, is very simple:

#### directory-mapping-file

```
/path/to/dir1/sub1    /path/to/dir2/subsub1
/path/to/dir1/sub2    /paht/to/dir2/semisub-2
```

That is, it contains the name of the subdirectory under `dir1` and the name under `dir2`.

#### Directory copying code

The way you use it is then similar to this (being careful to do vaguely appropriate error checking):

```
while read src tgt
do
    [ ! -d "$src" ] && { echo "$0: Not a directory: $src" 1>&2; continue; }
    [ ! -d "$tgt" ] && { echo "$0: Not a directory: $tgt" 1>&2; continue; }
    echo "Mapping files under $src to $tgt"
    (
    if cd "$src"
    then cp -rf . "$tgt"
    else echo "$0: Oops! cd $src failed" 1>&2
    fi
    )
done < /path/to/dir1/directory-mapping-file
```

Obviously, you can locate the directory mapping file anywhere convenient.  Note that unless you are careful (as shown) to use the correct relative names, you can end up with unwanted directory hierarchies under your target directory.  Definitely experiment and double-check that the script gives you what you need.  Also note that the `cd` command is done in an explicit sub-shell (the `( ... )` notation.  This isolates the change of directory to the sub-shell, which is generally more resilient that doing the `cd` in the parent shell.  If the error message from the `cd` command is sufficient, then the `else` clause is not needed, and you could reduce that all to:

```
cd "$src" && cp -rf . "$tgt"
```

Note, too, that I quote the names; that may be old-school shell scripting, but if you ever change to a system where pathnames contain spaces, it is easier to get scripts to work sanely with a variety of shells if you enclose the names in quotes at all times.

A nice refinement is to allow comments and blank lines in the file:

```
sed -e 's/#.*//' -e '/^[ \t]*$/d' /path/to/dir1/directory-mapping-file |
while read src tgt
do
    ...as above...
done
```

Note that the `\t` probably needs to be an actual tab (but it is more than a little difficult to show a tab in Markdown).  I have a script I call nbncl (non-blank, non-comment lines) which encapsulates the logic of the `sed` command shown (though it is actually a non-minimal Perl script). Using that gives:

```
nbncl /path/to/dir1/directory-mapping-file |
while read src tgt
...as before...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but my subdirectories are not named the same thing as each other (they each have unique names). Also, I don't want to remove the entire sub* directory. I only want to copy the new files into it, overwriting any pre-existing duplicates.

Comment: If you value your sanity, use consistent names.  If you're hobbled by other people's insanity, then you'll have to specify a mapping between the directories under `/path/to/dir1` and `/path/to/dir2`, probably by a file (and let's hope for your sake that the pathnames don't contain spaces!).  You can then do: `while read src dst; do cp -fr $src $dst; done < directory-mapping-file`.

Comment: Ah yes, my sanity. Already mostly gone, I'm afraid, and these subdirs are client names. My decision, but an old one that I can't really change now. So this seems like it would work fine for me with the mapping file. But if you wouldn't mind, can you walk me through what the file would look like?

Comment: Wow, first rate answer, Jonathan, thank you! I'll comment again when I've got it all set up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `rsync` with something like:

```
rsync -av --exclude abberation dir1/ dir2
```

The trailing slash on `dir1/` is important as it causes `rsync` to copy the contents of `dir1`, not the directory itself. If you want to delete files not in the original tree, use `--delete`, otherwise, they will be left alone.

Comment: I may not have been clear enough in what I wrote, because I think this will replace the contents of `dir1` with the contents of `dir2`, right? But what I'm trying to do is replace the contents of each `subnum` with the contents of `dir2`, so I need to somehow loops through each or something like that.

Comment: Also, I realized I had reversed dir1 and dir2 in one sentence above. I've corrected the error (see Edit: in original). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let's go with `rsync -av --exclude abberation src/ dest`. This will copy all the files and subdirectories of `src` into `dest`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but this still is not going to iterate over my many subfolders, using each one as a new dest, correct?